# how to color a cell if the value in it is different from the cell above?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a row of cells, and I want the whole row to be colored if a cell, on a specific column has a different value from the cell above it. e.g.

```
      +
a b c d e
x y z d k
b d s d 2
a a a a f    < color this whole row >
g j k a q
p o i b d    < color this whole row >
      +
```

*In the example abve the relevant column is marked with '+'.*

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use Conditional Formatting, or try this short VBA macro:

```
Sub ColorMeRed()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To N
        If Cells(i - 1, 4).Value <> Cells(i, 4).Value Then
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]